# Is there any difference between でしょう and でしょ besides politeness level?

Tags: usage, contractions

I understand that でしょ is a contraction of でしょう used in very casual speech. Besides that difference in the degree of politeness, do they also have any difference in meaning or usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hardly think there is any difference there. However, as you mentioned, "でしょ" is only used in very casual situations, so it's best to avoid it outside of everyday conversation.

However, I personally think that "でしょ" tends to be used at the end of questions and "でしょう" at the end of affirmative sentences.

Comment: "でしょ at the end of questions, でしょう at the end of statments": this is consistent with what someone said at https://hinative.com/ja/questions/123322#answer-33132887.  I would actually consider this to be a material difference. I wonder if some grammar book or dictionary might point out this distinction?

Comment: @max Uhm I don't think so... since they both are (most of time) interchangeable, so I don't think I can find a good document for it. [here](http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/mt/ja/gmod/contents/explanation/075.html) you can see the usage of でしょう, I can find only four things in this document that are not interchangeable, which is (1), (2), (3-A), (7). I have a sense that でしょ should not be used here in context, but I don't feel like I can explain it well. Sorry...

Comment: @max I found [article](https://www.kokugobunpou.com/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99/#gsc.tab=0) about it! I hope this solves your question.